# Referencing a library project in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I would like to use Google Play Service as a library project for my app.

I follow the instructions here - http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

The main question is how do i reference "google-play-services_lib" in the AndroidManifest.xml?

I type this in AndroidManifest.xml but error says (invalid character "-" in activity)

```
<manifest>
  ...
  <application>
  ...
    <activity android:name="com.example.myApp.MainActivity.library.google-play-services_lib" />
  ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Anyone can advise? Thanks.

Comment: @antimo thanks fellow sporean! same school :)

Comment: No problem! And if possible, check the answer to mark this question as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reference the library in manifest file. If you already followed the steps to reference a library project in [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject), then you can directly use the content of the library in your code.